# isBundle() in Magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.4

How do you tell if a product page is set up as a bundle in Magento 1.4?  I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

this code should work in your product page (catalog/product/view.phtml):

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
if($product->getTypeId() === 'bundle'){
    // Something…
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  While I had to use a different solution this definitely worked for determining if a product is a bundle.

Answer (score 20):

`if ($_product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
    echo 'Bundled';
}`